# Spark Job gets iddle after attempting to count distinct values of a column dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I am stuck at solving an issue that arises when trying to run operations on a spark dataframe, which was created out of a txt file containing user events. A view to this dataframe (200k rows) is :

| timestamp | user_hash | browser_name | os_name | city_name | country_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-10-12 17:01:01 | f4fdd9e55192e9475... | Safari | iOS | Bristol | United Kingdom |
| 2014-10-12 17:01:01 | 0ae53126499336757... | Safari | iOS | Basildon | United Kingdom |
| 2014-10-12 17:01:01 | c5ac174ee153f7e57... | Chrome | Linux | Totteridge | United Kingdom |
| ------------------- | -------------------- | ------------ | ------- | ---------- | -------------- |

Well, on this df I try to get some statistics running the following lines:

```py
df.groupBy("city_name").count().orderBy(desc("count")).show(5)
df.groupBy("country_name").count().orderBy(desc("count")).show(5)
```

That reads as get top 5 countries based on number of events (rows).

As of now is taking ages to compute > 120s. As I am new to this technology, perhaps some concepts I still don't understand, as it might be the case that I am missing some detail at creating spark context or Spark Session, that is, with the wrong configuration parameters. Someone pointed out that it might be due to spark running on the driver and not on executors. If so, how I fix this?.
Its at creating a spark context or spark session with the right parameters?.

Currently in my code I create a spark session as follows :

```py
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
```

Then df is created like this :

```py
df = spark.read.option("lineSep", "\n").text(filepath)
```

Any feedback is appreciated regarding debugging code as well as suggestions at improving the description of my issue.
Cheers

Comment: It is a `groupBy` and will be handled in the main node.

Comment: is your data in a `csv` or `txt`?

Comment: data is a .gzip file, it's binary, but providing .text(*.gzip) works fine too

Comment: @Lamanus, how would you speed up counting the occurrences of distinct values on both columns then?. Any clue as for why it takes that much time?.

Comment: I suggest you unzip the file or use different compression format (eg lzo, bzip2). gzip file is unsplittable, meaning you will not get any parallel processing benefit from Spark.

Comment: @Hitobat by loading the unzipped file the computation goes down to 130s, so that's 70s less than in the previous runs.